# What this below Sample data represents?

Tags: flutter, graph, linechart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am trying to implement graph in my flutter app. I was looking at this flutter package and i did not understand this sampleData. I understood that its List of maps. But i don't know how to convert traditional graph data(co-ordinates data) into this fashion.
can someone please to help me understanding this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_candlesticks/flutter_candlesticks.dart';
void main() {
List sampleData = [
{"open":50.0, "high":100.0, "low":40.0, "close":80, "volumeto":5000.0},
{"open":80.0, "high":90.0, "low":55.0, "close":65, "volumeto":4000.0},
{"open":65.0, "high":120.0, "low":60.0, "close":90, "volumeto":7000.0},
{"open":90.0, "high":95.0, "low":85.0, "close":80, "volumeto":2000.0},
{"open":80.0, "high":85.0, "low":40.0, "close":50, "volumeto":3000.0},
];
runApp(
new MaterialApp(
  home: new Scaffold(
    body: new Center(
      child: new Container(
        height: 500.0,
        child: new OHLCVGraph(
            data: sampleData,
            enableGridLines: false,
            volumeProp: 0.2
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
)
);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the sample data

Comment: Actually I was trying to get historical data from an api and to show it in graphical way. I thought API's data will be in co-ordinates, but to my surprise it is also in this format (OPEN :,HIGH,LOW:,CLOSE:). So i don't have to convert now. But i am not getting What are these OPEN and CLOSE parameters.

Comment: what kind of chart you want to use and show how your data looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like data for stock trading. The OPEN is the price of the stock at the day opening and CLOSE is the closing price. Their are other extreme values such as high and low provided.

A dead give away is the importing of package:flutter_candlesticks. Candle sticks is a type of graph that is popularly used in graphs for stocks.